# How to ingest GCP monitoring metrics into Prometheus

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a GCP project with various metrics that are gathered automatically by GCP monitoring (ex. Stackdriver). I also have a GKE cluster running a prometheus server. I am trying to ingest all metrics from Stackdriver into the Prometheus server but I am not sure what is the best way of achieving that. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S.: I have found the [stackdriver exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/stackdriver_exporter) but I am not sure if there is any other alternatives.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus) ,Prometheus server with Stackdriver collector Deprecated and support  [depends on Prometheus server version](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar#compatibility) . IMPORTANT: The Stackdriver Prometheus sidecar is in maintenance mode and will not receive any new feature updates. Please review the recommendations in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus) before proceeding with any new deployments.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Is it not a better pattern to use managed service for prometheus on Google Cloud and use Cloud Monitoring (with PromQL) to query your metrics?

Comment: I hope the above information clarifies your queries. Could you please let me know if you have any additional queries and I am happy to assist further

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar . This is quite clear.

Comment: @Nick : I have posted this as a solution which helped you to give some solution to your issue. Please accept and upvote if the answer has some useful information for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 1):

**I have converted my comments as an answer :**

As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus) ,Prometheus server with Stackdriver collector Deprecated and support  [depends on Prometheus server version](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar#compatibility) . IMPORTANT: The Stackdriver Prometheus sidecar is in maintenance mode and will not receive any new feature updates. Please review the recommendations in the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus) before proceeding with any new deployments.